# Android - FirstApp Issue (SEND Button does not work)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

Currently trying to use the android website training facility to try and understand how to build apps for android. I am having issues on 'Starting second activity'. The send button does not seem to work, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried to read through the forum as others have had issues but I cannot seem to resolve my problem. I have re-read the android tutorial provided on the site but I have done the steps exactly as shown. I would appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void sendMessage (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
       @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Get the message from the intent
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

            // Create the text view
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setTextSize(40);
            textView.setText(message);

            // Set the text view as the activity layout
            setContentView(textView);
        }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.testapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.testapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

logcat:

```
07-11 19:34:26.244: D/dalvikvm(12926): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
07-11 19:34:26.684: D/AndroidRuntime(12939): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
07-11 19:34:26.684: D/AndroidRuntime(12939): CheckJNI is OFF
07-11 19:34:26.684: D/AndroidRuntime(12939): setted country_code = UK &amp; IRE
07-11 19:34:26.684: D/AndroidRuntime(12939): setted countryiso_code = GB
07-11 19:34:26.689: D/AndroidRuntime(12939): setted sales_code = BTU
07-11 19:34:26.689: D/AndroidRuntime(12939): readGMSProperty: start
07-11 19:34:26.689: D/AndroidRuntime(12939): readGMSProperty: already setted!!
07-11 19:34:26.689: D/AndroidRuntime(12939): readGMSProperty: end
07-11 19:34:26.689: D/AndroidRuntime(12939): addProductProperty: start
07-11 19:34:26.699: D/dalvikvm(12939): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
07-11 19:34:26.699: D/dalvikvm(12939): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
07-11 19:34:26.709: D/dalvikvm(12939): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
07-11 19:34:26.709: D/dalvikvm(12939): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
07-11 19:34:26.824: D/MotionEngine(2240): [@@@ Motion Engine @@@] GetMotionScenarioId -0.028730 0.114922 9.682152 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 51 20
07-11 19:34:26.879: D/dalvikvm(12939): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 153 unimplemented (abstract) methods
07-11 19:34:26.914: D/AndroidRuntime(12939): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
07-11 19:34:26.964: I/power(2240): *** acquire_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1  freq : 1000000 
07-11 19:34:26.964: D/PowerManagerService(2240): acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1000000  uid : 1000  pid : 2240  tag : ActivityManager
07-11 19:34:26.964: W/ActivityManager(2240): mDVFSLock.acquire()
07-11 19:34:26.969: D/Launcher.HomeFragment(24197): onPause
07-11 19:34:26.969: D/widget(24197): [MSC_HERO_Accu_JB]>>> WC:1218 [0:0]  fireOP
07-11 19:34:26.969: D/Launcher(24197): onPause, Launcher: 1104847976
07-11 19:34:26.969: D/widget(24197): [MSC_HERO_Accu_JB]>>> WC:1028 [0:0]  onPause 
07-11 19:34:26.989: D/AndroidRuntime(12939): Shutting down VM
07-11 19:34:26.989: I/AndroidRuntime(12939): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_3' failed
07-11 19:34:26.994: D/dalvikvm(12939): GC_CONCURRENT freed 103K, 86% free 600K/4096K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 4ms
07-11 19:34:26.994: D/jdwp(12939): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
07-11 19:34:26.994: D/dalvikvm(12939): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
07-11 19:34:26.994: D/dalvikvm(12950): Late-enabling CheckJNI
07-11 19:34:26.999: D/dalvikvm(1908): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
07-11 19:34:27.014: E/jdwp(12950): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
07-11 19:34:27.014: D/dalvikvm(12950): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
07-11 19:34:27.014: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): id=1289(227) createSurf 0x4194b0c4 (1x1),1 flag=400, uestapp
07-11 19:34:27.014: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): SurfaceFlinger : eMagnificationFactorChanged.  magnificationFactor=1.0
07-11 19:34:27.014: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): SurfaceFlinger : eZoomPositionChanged.  zoomX=0.0 zoomY=0.0
07-11 19:34:27.014: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:27.029: D/dalvikvm(1908): GC_EXPLICIT freed 39K, 7% free 12110K/12931K, paused 12ms+1ms, total 31ms
07-11 19:34:27.029: D/dalvikvm(1908): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
07-11 19:34:27.029: V/WindowManager(2240): rotationForOrientationLw(orient=-1, last=0); user=0 USER_ROTATION_LOCKED mLidState=-1 mDockMode=0 mHdmiPlugged=false mAccelerometerDefault=false sensorRotation=-1
07-11 19:34:27.044: D/WindowManager(2240): PhoneWindowManager: focusChangedLw
07-11 19:34:27.044: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:27.044: D/WindowManager(2240): mInputFocus is not null.
07-11 19:34:27.044: D/WindowManager(2240): mInputFocus is not null.
07-11 19:34:27.049: D/MotionEngine(2240): [@@@ Motion Engine @@@] MOVE Recognition ############  40 
07-11 19:34:27.049: D/dalvikvm(1908): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 7% free 12110K/12931K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 23ms
07-11 19:34:27.049: D/dalvikvm(1908): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
07-11 19:34:27.069: D/Launcher(24197): onTrimMemory. Level: 20
07-11 19:34:27.074: D/dalvikvm(1908): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 7% free 12110K/12931K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 23ms
07-11 19:34:27.074: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:27.079: D/WindowManager(2240): mInputFocus is not null.
07-11 19:34:27.084: D/WindowManager(2240): mInputFocus is not null.
07-11 19:34:27.084: D/WindowManager(2240): mInputFocus is not null.
07-11 19:34:27.104: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:27.104: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:27.104: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:27.104: D/WindowManager(2240): mInputFocus is not null.
07-11 19:34:27.104: D/WindowManager(2240): mInputFocus is not null.
07-11 19:34:27.104: D/WindowManager(2240): mInputFocus is not null.
07-11 19:34:27.119: D/dalvikvm(2240): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1598K, 56% free 24570K/55111K, paused 18ms+18ms, total 148ms
07-11 19:34:27.139: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:27.139: D/WindowManager(2240): mInputFocus is not null.
07-11 19:34:27.139: D/WindowManager(2240): mInputFocus is not null.
07-11 19:34:27.174: D/WindowManager(2240): mInputFocus is not null.
07-11 19:34:27.204: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): id=1290(1) createSurf 0x4111a4b4 (1x1),1 flag=400, NainActivit
07-11 19:34:27.204: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): SurfaceFlinger : eMagnificationFactorChanged.  magnificationFactor=1.0
07-11 19:34:27.204: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): SurfaceFlinger : eZoomPositionChanged.  zoomX=0.0 zoomY=0.0
07-11 19:34:27.204: D/WindowManager(2240): PhoneWindowManager: focusChangedLw
07-11 19:34:27.204: D/STATUSBAR-StatusBarManagerService(2240): setSystemUiVisibility(0x0)
07-11 19:34:27.204: D/STATUSBAR-StatusBarManagerService(2240): manageDisableList what=0x0 pkg=WindowManager.LayoutParams
07-11 19:34:27.209: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:27.219: D/libEGL(12950): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
07-11 19:34:27.219: D/libEGL(12950): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
07-11 19:34:27.219: D/libEGL(12950): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
07-11 19:34:27.224: D/(12950): Device driver API match
07-11 19:34:27.224: D/(12950): Device driver API version: 10
07-11 19:34:27.224: D/(12950): User space API version: 10 
07-11 19:34:27.224: D/(12950): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
07-11 19:34:27.254: D/OpenGLRenderer(12950): Enabling debug mode 0
07-11 19:34:27.269: I/ClipboardServiceEx(2240): Send intent for dismiss clipboard dialog inside hideCurrentInputLocked() !
07-11 19:34:27.314: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:27.329: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:27.334: D/Launcher.HomeFragment(24197): onStop
07-11 19:34:27.334: D/Launcher(24197): onStop, Launcher: 1104847976
07-11 19:34:27.334: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:27.429: I/power(2240): *** release_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1 
07-11 19:34:27.429: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:27.429: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): id=1287 Removed Mauncher idx=1 MapSz=6
07-11 19:34:27.429: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): id=1287 Removed Mauncher idx=-2 MapSz=6
07-11 19:34:27.429: D/PowerManagerService(2240): releaseDVFSLockLocked : all DVFS_MIN_LIMIT are released 
07-11 19:34:27.429: W/ActivityManager(2240): mDVFSLock.release()
07-11 19:34:27.529: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:27.529: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): id=1289 Removed uestapp idx=3 MapSz=5
07-11 19:34:27.534: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): id=1289 Removed uestapp idx=-2 MapSz=5
07-11 19:34:27.534: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:27.539: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:27.874: D/MotionEngine(2240): [@@@ Motion Engine @@@] GetMotionScenarioId -0.028730 0.047884 9.768343 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 51 20
07-11 19:34:28.924: D/MotionEngine(2240): [@@@ Motion Engine @@@] GetMotionScenarioId -0.047884 0.067038 9.653421 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 51 20
07-11 19:34:29.369: D/MotionEngine(2240): [@@@ Motion Engine @@@] MOVE Recognition ############  40 
07-11 19:34:29.974: D/MotionEngine(2240): [@@@ Motion Engine @@@] GetMotionScenarioId -0.009577 0.134075 9.758766 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 51 20
07-11 19:34:30.299: I/InputReader(2240): Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.1652 ]
07-11 19:34:30.299: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-11 19:34:30.299: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-11 19:34:30.299: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-11 19:34:30.299: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-11 19:34:30.299: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-11 19:34:30.349: I/InputReader(2240): Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=]
07-11 19:34:30.349: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
07-11 19:34:30.349: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
07-11 19:34:30.349: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
07-11 19:34:30.424: D/KJH(2643): [KeyboardView-init] mGuestureTraceKeyboardGapForXt9_9 : 0
07-11 19:34:30.454: D/ApplicationPolicy(2240): isStatusBarNotificationAllowed: packageName = android
07-11 19:34:30.454: D/ApplicationPolicy(2240): isStatusBarNotificationAllowed: packageName = android
07-11 19:34:30.454: D/PhoneStatusBar(2514): addNotification score=0
07-11 19:34:30.454: D/STATUSBAR-NotificationService(2240): Noti Alert - mSystemReady:true, AlertEnabled:true
07-11 19:34:30.454: D/PowerManagerService(2240): mIsSipVisible : true
07-11 19:34:30.454: D/STATUSBAR-NotificationService(2240): Noti Alert - mSystemReady:true, AlertEnabled:true
07-11 19:34:30.459: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): id=1291(271) createSurf 0x41950f14 (720x531),1 flag=0, JnputMethod
07-11 19:34:30.459: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): SurfaceFlinger : eMagnificationFactorChanged.  magnificationFactor=1.0
07-11 19:34:30.459: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): SurfaceFlinger : eZoomPositionChanged.  zoomX=0.0 zoomY=0.0
07-11 19:34:30.459: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:30.464: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:30.469: D/StatusBar(2514): expanding top notification at 4entry.userCollapsed() = false
07-11 19:34:30.474: D/StatusBar(2514): expanding top notification at 4entry.userCollapsed() = false
07-11 19:34:30.519: D/dalvikvm(2643): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2347K, 27% free 16774K/22855K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
07-11 19:34:30.579: W/SignalStrength(2240): getGsmLevel=4
07-11 19:34:30.579: W/SignalStrength(2240): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 14 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 gsm|lte 4)
07-11 19:34:30.579: W/SignalStrength(2514): getGsmLevel=4
07-11 19:34:30.579: W/SignalStrength(2514): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 14 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 gsm|lte 4)
07-11 19:34:30.579: W/SignalStrength(2514): getGsmLevel=4
07-11 19:34:30.579: W/SignalStrength(2514): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 14 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 gsm|lte 4)
07-11 19:34:30.579: W/SignalStrength(2240): getGsmDbm=-85
07-11 19:34:30.579: W/SignalStrength(2240): getDbm=-85
07-11 19:34:30.579: W/SignalStrength(2240): getGsmAsuLevel=14
07-11 19:34:30.579: W/SignalStrength(2240): getAsuLevel=14
07-11 19:34:30.579: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2514): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 14 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 gsm|lte 4 level=4
07-11 19:34:30.589: D/dalvikvm(2643): GC_CONCURRENT freed 281K, 22% free 18046K/22855K, paused 11ms+2ms, total 30ms
07-11 19:34:30.589: D/dalvikvm(2643): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
07-11 19:34:30.614: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:30.849: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:30.849: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:31.029: D/MotionEngine(2240): [@@@ Motion Engine @@@] GetMotionScenarioId -0.019154 0.143652 9.921572 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 51 20
07-11 19:34:31.034: I/InputReader(2240): Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.1653 ]
07-11 19:34:31.034: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-11 19:34:31.034: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-11 19:34:31.034: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-11 19:34:31.034: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-11 19:34:31.034: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-11 19:34:31.039: E/AudioPolicyService(1910): getOutput() tid 1910 ++
07-11 19:34:31.039: E/AudioPolicyService(1910): getOutput() tid 1910 --
07-11 19:34:31.039: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): getOutput() stream 1, samplingRate 0, format 0, channelMask 3, flags 0
07-11 19:34:31.039: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): getOutputsForDevice device 0002 -> 0002
07-11 19:34:31.039: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): getOutput() returns output 2
07-11 19:34:31.039: E/AudioPolicyService(1910): getOutput() tid 2199 ++
07-11 19:34:31.039: E/AudioPolicyService(1910): getOutput() tid 2199 --
07-11 19:34:31.039: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): getOutput() stream 1, samplingRate 0, format 0, channelMask 3, flags 0
07-11 19:34:31.039: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): getOutputsForDevice device 0002 -> 0002
07-11 19:34:31.039: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): getOutput() returns output 2
07-11 19:34:31.039: E/AudioPolicyService(1910): getOutput() tid 7156 ++
07-11 19:34:31.039: E/AudioPolicyService(1910): getOutput() tid 7156 --
07-11 19:34:31.039: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): getOutput() stream 1, samplingRate 44100, format 1, channelMask 3, flags 4
07-11 19:34:31.039: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): getOutputsForDevice device 0002 -> 0002
07-11 19:34:31.039: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): getOutput() returns output 2
07-11 19:34:31.044: V/LvOutput(1910): initCheck: 0
07-11 19:34:31.044: V/LvOutput(1910): attachEffects: attach processing to output 2, stream 1, session 2235, mode 0
07-11 19:34:31.044: V/LvOutput(1910): attachEffects: no output processing needs to be attached to this stream
07-11 19:34:31.044: V/LvOutput(1910): LvOutput::setAllProcessorEnabled(false) mOutputs.size(0)
07-11 19:34:31.044: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): startOutput() output 2, stream 1, session 2235
07-11 19:34:31.044: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
07-11 19:34:31.044: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): getNewDevice() selected device 2
07-11 19:34:31.044: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0 
07-11 19:34:31.044: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): setOutputDevice() prevDevice 0002
07-11 19:34:31.044: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): setOutputDevice() setting same device 0002 or null device for output 2
07-11 19:34:31.044: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): releaseOutput() 2
07-11 19:34:31.044: I/AudioMixer(1910): setParameter(TRACK, FORMAT, 0x1)
07-11 19:34:31.044: E/AudioMixer(1910): MOON > checkSEC_PCM ++ 1
07-11 19:34:31.044: I/AudioHardwareTinyALSA(1910): AudioStreamOutALSA::write setDevice
07-11 19:34:31.044: D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA(1910): OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
07-11 19:34:31.044: D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA(1910): OutALSA::setDevice: mDevice 0x2, newDevice = 0x2
07-11 19:34:31.044: D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA(1910): setOutputVolume
07-11 19:34:31.044: D/TinyUCM(1910): setModifier Normal, en=1
07-11 19:34:31.044: I/AudioHardwareTinyALSA(1910): OutALSA::setDevice: mHandle NULL mode[0], Device[00000002] 
07-11 19:34:31.044: I/AudioHardwareTinyALSA(1910): Open: mDefaults->direction=0 device=0
07-11 19:34:31.044: D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA(1910): Channel: 2, Samplerate: 44100, Format: 0, Peroid Size: 1024, Period Count: 4
07-11 19:34:31.044: I/AudioHardwareTinyALSA(1910): before pcm_prepare
07-11 19:34:31.044: D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA(1910): setPcmInterface: Stream=0x1, iSamplerate=8000++
07-11 19:34:31.044: D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA(1910): setPcmInterface--
07-11 19:34:31.089: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): id=1292(272) createSurf 0x41950f74 (1x1),1 flag=0, QopupWindow
07-11 19:34:31.094: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): SurfaceFlinger : eMagnificationFactorChanged.  magnificationFactor=1.0
07-11 19:34:31.094: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): SurfaceFlinger : eZoomPositionChanged.  zoomX=0.0 zoomY=0.0
07-11 19:34:31.094: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:31.114: I/InputReader(2240): Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=]
07-11 19:34:31.114: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
07-11 19:34:31.114: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
07-11 19:34:31.114: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
07-11 19:34:31.114: V/LvOutput(1910): initCheck: 0
07-11 19:34:31.114: V/LvOutput(1910): detachEffects: detach processing for output 2, stream 1, session 2235
07-11 19:34:31.114: V/LvOutput(1910): detachEffects: no output processing was attached to this stream
07-11 19:34:31.114: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): stopOutput() output 2, stream 1, session 2235
07-11 19:34:31.114: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
07-11 19:34:31.119: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): getNewDevice() selected device 0
07-11 19:34:31.119: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184 
07-11 19:34:31.119: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): setOutputDevice() prevDevice 0002
07-11 19:34:31.119: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): setOutputDevice() setting same device 0000 or null device for output 2
07-11 19:34:31.169: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:31.199: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): id=1292 Removed QopupWindow idx=4 MapSz=6
07-11 19:34:31.199: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2240): setHidden false
07-11 19:34:31.199: I/SurfaceFlinger(1907): id=1292 Removed QopupWindow idx=-2 MapSz=6
07-11 19:34:31.204: I/InputReader(2240): Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.1654 ]
07-11 19:34:31.204: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-11 19:34:31.204: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-11 19:34:31.204: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-11 19:34:31.204: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-11 19:34:31.204: I/InputDispatcher(2240): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-11 19:34:31.209: E/AudioPolicyService(1910): getOutput() tid 2199 ++
07-11 19:34:31.209: E/AudioPolicyService(1910): getOutput() tid 2199 --
07-11 19:34:31.209: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1910): getOutput() stream 1, samplingRate
```

Comment: what is the error?. Have you declared your second activity in the Manifest file?

Comment: `seem to work` means????

Comment: This is like the 5th time I've seen this exact question.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I know I do apologise for that. New to this and their problem seemed to be that they did not initialise (start) the activity.

I have declared the activity infact Eclipse did it on its on. I will edit my question and add the manifest file.

Comment: The funny thing is, I think almost everyone who has started Android Dev with Eclipse ran that EXACT tutorial.  And every one of us ran into a similar problem.  I'm afraid you're going to have to get used to going over your code line by line to identify prolems like this.  Because you are still at the very beginning.  :)

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils logcat added, hope it helps :(


 yeah will do. Thought it would be simple but this is terrifying..I have already had problems with the adt android bundle that the android site provided a week ago, and now this. I hope it gets better and I don't run into so many problems

Answer (score 0):

I think when you create your Intent object, you have to do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```

Because in this case, you are probably getting the context of the View, instead of the activity's context.
If it doesn't work, please paste your logcat console, then we can see what's the error you're getting.

Comment: This did not work I tried it. The logcat console I can see it but the list keeps changing and there will be a lot of code, do you still want me to post it?

Comment: @RaúlOmaña its up now :)

Comment: Perfect! what was the problem?

Comment: @RaúlOmaña send button is not working.. this is to do with the android tutorial on the site, namely 'starting the second activity'

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `DisplayMessageActivity`

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(message);

LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(this);
linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); 
linear.addView(textView);

//set the text view as the activity layout
setContentView(linear);
```

Comment: Try removing that `android:parentActivityName` from your DisplayMessageActivity in Manifest

Comment: It means that it is not working as it should...or doing what it is meant to do...do you get me?